# Equal spacing between items inside a RecyclerView that is using a StaggeredGridLayoutManager?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Currently trying to do that by using this class:

```
public class EqualItemSpacingDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private int space;

    public EqualItemSpacingDecoration(int space) {
        this.space = space;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        outRect.bottom = space;
        if (parent.getChildLayoutPosition(view) < 2)
            outRect.top = space;
        if (parent.getChildLayoutPosition(view) % 2 == 0) {
            outRect.left = space;
            outRect.right = space / 2;
        } else {
            outRect.left = space / 2;
            outRect.right = space;
        }
    }

}
```

And use it with this code:

```
recycler.addItemDecoration(new EqualItemSpacingDecoration(12));
```

But the spacing isn't equal. The third item in the screenshot below has an incorrect spacing :
[image: Spacing is not correct with the third item.]

How will I be able to fix this issue?